# How hide options in select list angular?

Tags: angularjs

There is an object:

```
0 : { id : 1, value : 2},
1 : { id : 2, value : 3}
```

And select list:

```
<select id="sec">
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="3"></option>
</select>
```

How to hide all option `in id="sec"` after click to option `id = 2` from first select. So, show only:

```
<option value="1"></option>
<option value="1"></option>
```

I tried to add `ng-model="selectList" ng-change(selectList)` as to get selected value. Now how to compare seleted value from object and hide options from second select?

Comment: What is reason to set me minus?

Answer (score 0):

My own solution:

```
<?= form_dropdown('specialization', $specCategory['name'], array(), 'ng-model="specialization"');?>
<select ng-model="doctors" name="doctor">
<option ng-show="specialization == {{value.UsersSpecializationIdSpecialization}}" value="{{value.UsersWorkSpaceIdUser}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in options">{{value.DetailToUsersName}}</option>
</select>
```